Как изменить код, чтобы считать кратчайший путь через несколько точек?
Есть такой код:
def main():
    load_dotenv()

    ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

    g_walk = ox.graph_from_place('Россия, Челябинск', network_type='walk')

    orig_node = ox.nearest_nodes(g_walk,
                            61.303601265871286,55.19074976590795)

    dest_node = ox.nearest_nodes(g_walk,
                            61.36993818321634,55.15600112043476)

    route = nx.shortest_path(g_walk,
                     orig_node,
                     dest_node,
                     weight='length')

    map = Map()

    route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(G=g_walk, route=route, route_map=map)

    route_map.save('map.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Он рассчитывает и отображает на карте кратчайший путь между двумя точками. Но как изменить его так, чтобы он рассчитывал кратчайший путь, проходящий через несколько точек?

Вероятно, с помощью алгоритма Дийкстры. в качестве базового примера можно использовать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723854/networkx-finding-the-shortest-path-to-one-of-multiple-nodes-in-graph
